# Getting a list of files modified after an apt-get upgrade or intstall?

Tags: files, apt

I would like to run AIDE or tripwire to make sure executables/configuration files/... do not get modified by malware.  Or at least notify me if they do get modified.

I would like to get a list of files modified during `apt get upgrade` and `apt-get install` to tell me how to update the AIDE/tripwire database.

This includes files modified during pre/post processing.

Answer (score 0):

[Tools like AIDE and Tripwire are not very useful](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10361/tripwire-is-it-security-theater) because only detect attacks that are not very clever. If an attacker can get root, they needn't bother to modify system binaries, or they can fake data for the monitoring system, by infecting the kernel. Tripwire may be useful in that it reports changes as soon as they occur, before the attacker has had time to erases their traces; this requires that the logs are sent immediately to an outside machine that remains trustworthy.

That being said, if you want to know what permissions are modified as part of the `apt-get` run, you can trace the system calls that it makes. Interrupt the trace after the run, as it may be tracing daemons that are (re)started during the upgrade.

```
strace -o apt.strace -e openat,write sh -c '
  apt-get "$@"
  kill $PPID
' apt-get-wrapper upgrade
```

It would be cheaper to use [auditd](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/01/a-brief-introduction-to-auditd/), but the problem is how to filter the changes that are due to the APT run. I think you can do that by running `apt-get` with a different audit UID, which should be easy with a C wrapper; the remaining problem would be to not run the restarted daemons in that audit uid, for which I don't have a solution.

Comment: strace seems drastic as it will probably bog down the upgrade. I was hoping more for something that used apt or dpkg type programs or libraries relating to it.

Comment: @TLOlczyk Any file that gets modified is modified by `dpkg` or by its subprocesses, not by `apt-get`. Neither will know anything about files that aren't tracked by the package manager, such as files in `/etc` modifies from debconf settings or automatically generated files under `/usr`. There is no possible solution that relies on APT or `dpkg` alone, they don't have the information. You need to either log their subprocesses or compare the before and after state, which is also expensive.

Comment: As for the comments about AIDE and tripwire.. They seem dumb. I don't know the exact nature of realtime monitoring in either system. ( Especially  tripwire, since from what I remember of AIDE it has no realtime monitoring. ). However if one sets up a system similar to a thumbdrive with a minimal OS, no network, AIDE/tripwire and their databases, then that process would be highly effective at catching infections.

Comment: @TLOlczyk Neither AIDE nor Tripwire monitors the running kernel, so they won't detect an infection that directly affects the kernel. Tripwire (if set up correctly) will detect an infection that operates by modifying a system binary before it can elevate privileges.

Answer (score 0):

A simplistic approach would be to use `find`.  Example below assumes you're only interested in files changed in / and /var

```
touch /tmp/foo
apt get upgrade
find / /var -xdev -newer /tmp/foo -ls
```